# Displaying (if) link in a cell

Tags: php, hyperlink, echo, cell

The table cell in the below code is being used as part of a messaging system and it returns the url as a link to the attached file to the message.

```
echo '<td width="25%"><a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($row->file_attached).'">'.wp_get_attachment_url($row->file_attached).'</a></td>';
```

This is fine and works well, my problem is that I would like it to either only show the title of the file ( not the full url) 
or even better would be to have it print "file attached" as a link, but if there is no file to get could it say "no file attached"

I am a complete novice at this and I am trying to stuble my way through. It would be great if somebody could push me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just mean you want the text of the link to be different, this is really basic HTML (not PHP):

```
<a href="/some/url">some text for the link</a>
```

In your case, you have the URL repeated as the contents of the `<a>` tag, but you can put whatever you want there.

**Edit**: To only show the link if there is a link to show, you need an `if` statement, probably the simplest piece of programming logic there is:

```
if ( $row->file_attached ) {
    // echo a link
}
else {
    // echo something other than a link
}
```

Comment: No, I want the text to be different depending on if there is a file/link to return or not. ie,    <a href="/some/url">some text for the link</a> OR <a href="">No file attached</a>

Comment: I've edited my answer to also cover the second part of your question. This is all incredibly basic stuff, and I would strongly recommend you go away and read some introductory programming tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, I had being playing around with the "if" but I was trying to put the if in the cell, not the cell in the if!! Thanks, I'm very sleepy

Answer (score 0):

Try following. when attachement is found it displays your link, when its not found it just shows a message. It is not a good idea to have a link when no attachement is found, that will link to nowhere...

```
    if(wp_get_attachment_url($row->file_attached))
         echo '<td width="25%"><a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($row->file_attached).'">'.sometext.'</a></td>';

    else
          echo '<td width="25%">no file attached</td>';
```